# Why build of cordova ios with firebasex plugin fails?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugin-firebasex

I have XCode 14.3, Cordova iOS 6.3.0 and simple build of example code fails. Steps to reproduce are pretty simple:

```
cordova create test_app
cd test_app
cordova platform add ios
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex
cordova build ios
```

This fails with:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Crashlytics /Users/duoweb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloCordova-bxerqspwpkqevmdayoiuscnylvem/Build/Intermediates.noindex/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloCordova.build/Script-B80D9FA43B074894BF08E4F3.sh (in target 'HelloCordova' from project 'HelloCordova')
(1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
```

I have no idea why. Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup Cocoapods then you need to open the workspace in Xcode (not the project) so you can build your app with the pods.

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#ios-specific

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, I will not use "cordova build ios"at all ? Can you please be more specific, how I can successfully build this example app in my question ?

Comment: No you won't. You have to open the workspace in Xcode, so you have the projects and the pods, then build from xcode.